# Como crear y trabajar de forma correcta las migraciones en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy un poco confundida al trabajar con las migraciones en Django; me explico
tengo los comandos:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

¿Estos son comandos globales? o solo los puedo utilizar cuando modifique los modelos propios que trae Django?

¿Por qué pregunto esto?
estoy modificando un modelo que he creado.

### Modelo Empleado

```
from django.db import models
from src.apps.account.models import CustomUser

# Create your models here.
class Employee(models.Model):
    name_one = models.TextField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    name_two = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Employee.Profile"
        ordering = ["-name_one"]
        verbose_name = "Employee"
        verbose_name_plural = "Employees"
```

### Modelo Usuario personalizado

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField("email address", unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

trato de ejecutar

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

y no hace nada.
Pero si lo ejecuto con el nombre de la app si funciona.

```
python manage.py makemigrations employees
python manage.py migrate employees
```

Entonces tengo la duda

```
python manage.py makemigrations app1,app2,app3
python manage.py migrate app1,app2,app3,
```

ó nunca voy a usar de esta forma:

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Otra pregunta con relación a las migraciones
Como estoy usando un modelo personalizado para los usuarios, tengo que aplicar las migraciones por primera vez a ese modelo(account=CustomUser) primero y luego hacerlo de forma global ? así:?

```
python manage.py makemigrations employee, account
python manage.py migrate employee, account
```

Luego de forma global ?

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Ahí mis dudas de como trabajar, crear y utilizar las migraciones,
Me pueden orientar por favor.

Editando: Aqui esta mi archivo base de configuracion Django
Lo tengo separado para mayor organizacion.
C:\git\e-commerce\backend\api\src\settings\base.py
la carpeta llamada "api" es la carpeta del proyecto Django donde se encuentra manage.py

### base.py

```
# BASE APPS
BASE_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]
# THIRD APPS
THIRD_APPS = [
    "rest_framework",
]
# LOCAL APPS
LOCAL_APPS = [
    "src.apps.core",
    "src.apps.employees",
    "src.apps.account",
]
INSTALLED_APPS = BASE_APPS + THIRD_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# Tabla para autenticacion de usurios.
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account.CustomUser"
```

### development.py

```
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
...
...
}
```

### magene.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys

develoment_mode = "src.settings.development"
production_mode = "src.settings.production"
#  Current application environment
current_environment = develoment_mode


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", current_environment)
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir tu settings.py por favor, la sección de INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Listo ya esta editando,

Comment: Gracias, una duda mas, si estas colocando el AUTH_USER_MODEL en tu settings con tu modelo CustomUser?, tambien podrias agregar la estructura de tu proyecto(puedes agregarlo como imagen), y por ultimo cuando ejecutas el manage.py como le pasas tu archivo settings?

Comment: 1-  AUTH_USER_MODEL se encuentra 2 lineas mas abajo en installs_apps en mi archivo base.py
2- Fotos subidas
3- Modifique el manage.py para que me leea determinado archivo con mi settings. disculpa la demora apenas estoy llegando a mi casa